# Expo: Unable to resolve module index.ts. None of these files exist

Tags: react-native, expo, monorepo

I'm trying out this template located here (https://github.com/t3-oss/create-t3-turbo).

After installing the dependencies, I ran "pnpm dev" in the terminal. Expo gives this error

```
Error: Unable to resolve module ./index.ts from C:\Users\...\apps\expo/.: 
 
None of these files exist:
   * index.ts(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.cjs|.native.cjs|.cjs)
   * index.ts\index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.cjs|.native.cjs|.cjs)
     at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Users\...\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:153:15)
     at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\...\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:276:43)        
     at C:\Users\...\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:171:21
     at Server._resolveRelativePath (C:\Users\...\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1256:12)
     at async Server.requestProcessor [as _processBundleRequest] (C:\Users\...\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:529:37)     
     at async Server._processRequest (C:\Users\...\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:449:9)
```

index.ts definitely exists in the expo folder. Why is there an error being thrown?

It looks like "main" in the expo folder's package.json is what's throwing this error. I tried changing it to different values, but nothing helped.

Is anyone at least able to confirm they've reproduced the issue? It may be a bug with the template

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In case anyone else has this issue, the solution seems to be changing the versions of react and any other libraries that the console suggests.

I was getting a warning for 4 packages that said expo may not work as expected unless these version discrepancies are resolved.

I ignored that because it was my first time with a monorepo, and I thought the versions the template came with would work for everyone. From discussions with others, it seems like it works fine on ios, but not android

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by adding an `index.ts` file to the root of the project, which simply imports the needed entry file.
In my case:

```
// <project-root>/index.ts
import './src';
```